# Javascript change format from looping into array format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop thats looping through some data and getting some fiel values from it.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < mainData[0].main.length; i++) {

      var obj = mainData[0].main[i];
      var cars = obj.cars;
      console.log(cars);   
}
```

This is returning

```
26
65
34
12

etc
```

What I need is to put this in a format so it looks like this:

```
[26, 65, 34, 12]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: initialize an array and push value in it

Comment: where do you get `obj.sub.cars` from?

Comment: share the remaining code

Comment: How is `obj.sub.cars` changing with each iteration?

Comment: does `cars` contains a single value or an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
var result=[];

for (var i = 0; i < mainData[0].main.length; i++) {
  var cars = obj.sub.cars;
  result.push(cars);          
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just map the result and get an array.

```
cars = mainData[0].main.map(a => a.cars);
```

ES5

```
cars = mainData[0].main.map(function (a) { return a.cars; });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Print the array directly

If you are trying to print just the array, you can use `console.log(array)`instead of looping over everything in the array.

for example, assume this is the array.

```
var primes = [2,3,5,7];
console.log(primes);
```

will output `[2,3,5,7]`